# How can I connect to an Exchange 2013 server with OAuth?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, oauth

Our goal is to have our customers grant permission to access their email on an Exchange 2013 server with OAuth, without us having to store the customers' usernames and passwords. We already do this for Gmail and it works well and is easy. I'm anticipating a workflow like:

1. Customer comes to our site and clicks "Connect with Exchange".
2. Our server redirects to an Exchange-hosted site on the target domain.
3. User grants permissions.
4. Exchange redirects back to us with OAuth tokens in the payload.
5. Use these tokens to access user's email on that server via EWS.

Is this workflow supported by Exchange 2013? Is this available by default or does it require "configuration" on the Exchange side? (For instance, most Exchange servers need IMAP to be explicitly configured while EWS seems to be on by default.)

Comment: I'm in the same situation myself. Did you find any relevant information about this? Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry, we gave up on this project. I found no useful docs.